# What shape does magnetic dust take under the influence of its own magnetic field?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields

Recently, I came across some very powerful neodymium magnets (the flat cylinder kind), and I accidentally broke one by snapping two of them together quickly. What I noticed is that the two halves don't go together regularly anymore. Instead, they had to be in opposite directions. Obviously, north attracts south and south attracts north.

I then wondered about what would happen if one of these magnets were continually broken up, into smaller and smaller magnets. I eventually came to a cube with alternating up and down magnetic particles, with no overall magnetic field. But I have a feeling this isn't right. If a magnet were broken (or filed down) into dust, what shape would that dust actually take?

Comment: For symmetry reasons I would guess it's a shape with cylindrical symmetry, probably an oblate or prolate sphere, however, the experimental evidence with ferrofluids shows that for sufficiently strong magnetization they may probably form rather complex (and eventually probably fractal) shapes: https://www.carthage.edu/live/image/gid/16/width/375/height/250/4382_ferrofluidimage.jpg

Comment: perhaps the effect is similar to polar molecules like water, so they might form into droplets, or might just attract each other. After all, the shape of the field of a magnetic dipole is the same as that of an electric dipole.